# Input and Output filter for a video build filter?

Tags: c++, directshow

When I use a custom filter for merging videos from different source, do I have to take input from the input source directly?

Or do I take input from an encoder?

And regarding output, do I have to send it first to a encoder or send it directly to a filewriter filter?

Answer (score 0):

If the source is in the right format to merge (like rgb32) then you can take it direct from the source. But most of the time you will have compressed videos, so there will be a decoder before your filter.

To use the filewriter you need a muxer first, except you want to write a raw stream, nobody except you can open. I think you will also need an encoder to compress the big rgb stream to a smaller h264 or mpeg stream.

Comment: a typical graph looks like this reader->demux->decode->encode->mux->writer

Comment: yes. An encoder compresses the raw rgb or yuv frames to e.g. mpeg